# Get object from List<object> where property is null and order is the lowest

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class Menu
{
    public Menu()
    {

    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
 List<Menu> menus = new List<Menu>() // contains 10 items let's say.
```

How can I get the item from the list where the `Value == null` and the Order is the smallest values among items?

Example:

Menu items can have an order like this: `10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ...`

There are no items with the same order, each item has a unique number value.

I am interested to get the Menu when the Order is the smallest one and Value is null. In this case the item where Order is 10 and Value null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Linq for that:

```
 var result = menus.Where(x => x.Value == null).OrderBy(x => x.Order).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where takes only object with Value == null

OrderBy orders them by Order property

FirstOrDefault takes first value or returns null if there are none that match the query

```
 // This can be written in a shorter form
 var resultWithShorterLinq = menus.OrderBy(x => x.Order).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == null);
```

Both ways are equivalent, because with Linq you first build query with methods like Where, OrderBy, OrderByDescending... And only execute it when you call one of these methods:

```
query.ToList();
query.ToArray();
query.First();
query.FirstOrDefault();
etc...
```

And when using FirstOrDefault, don't forget to check if there is result found by checking if it's not null

```
if(result != null){
    // The result is found :)
}
else {
    // No results :(
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to achieve that:

```
var menuItem = menus.Where(m => m.Value == null).OrderBy(m=>m.Order).First();
```

This assumes that there is at least one item in the list. If there can be no items you can use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ ordering your List by Order then getting the first that has a null value

```
Menu mn = menus.OrderBy(x => x.Order).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value == null);
if(mn != null)
{
    // Got it
}
else
{
    // No match for your condition
}
```